# Puzzling GA4 Query Explorer Scenario

Tags: php, google-analytics-4

**THE PROBLEM**: Want PageViews by Country for last 30 days where the query string includes the Sellers posting id(s).

So a Seller might have multiple postings, so need to filter the Query String dim on those posting id's (five digits, eg.  68564).  A pagePathPlusQueryString would look like "https://www.xxxxx.com/php/yyyyy.php?topic=Search&category=merchandise&postid=68564".  The idea is to get a total tally of all posting hits by country, not individual, which of course could be done and tallied up in the PHP code.  Just figure it may be possible to do via GA4 by aggregations or dim filters manipulation.  Thus far, the result provides individual postid tallies for a given country.

Am using the following:

```
Date Range Start: 31daysAgo
Date Range End: yesterday
Metric: screenPageViews
Dimension:  country, pagePathPlusQueryString
Dim Filter: pagePagePlusQueryString
    Filter Type:  STRING and INLIST (Have tried both along with aggregation and orGroups but not getting the desired result
    Values: eg 68564, for INLIST would use the list of postids.
```

Any ideas how to get all postid queries by country to tally-up from the get go so the result for say three postids would look something like:

```
USA: 124
Canada: 67
France: 12
Mexico: 9
```

vs

```
USA: 90
Canada: 27
France: 12
Mexico: 3
USA: 30
Canada: 30
France: 12
Mexico: 2
USA: 4
Canada: 10
France: 12
Mexico: 4
```

Does inListFilter have a limit on how many values there can be?  Do not see one in the MAN page (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression#inlistfilter).

Thank you.
LarryG